# Autohotkey Hotstrings Using variables

Tags: autohotkey

Rigth now I have

:R:#bn:: \binom{}{}

#bn is my shortcut to create the binom

What I'd like to have is that I could type
#bn_a_b (or anything else)
and get \binom{a}{b} with each time I'm typing a,b could be different numbers or letters.

is that possible?

(Also usable for:
#for x creates
for x =   to

next x )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example make `#bn` be your hotstring, and then make that hotstring trigger an `Input`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm)</sup> command like so:

```
:*B0:#bn::
    Input, outp, L2 V
    characters := StrSplit(outp)
    SendInput, % "{BS 5}{Text}\binom{" characters[1] "}{" characters[2] "}"
return
```

`*` and `B0` [options](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Options) used for the hotstring to make it not require an [*ending character*](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#EndChars) and not be automatically backspaced so you can see the yourself type the whole thing first.

`L2` and `V` [options](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm#Parameters) used for the input command to limit its length to two characters and make the input visible while typing.

`{BS 5}`<sup>([docs1](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#keynames), [docs2](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Repeating_or_Holding_Down_a_Key))</sup> used to send five backspaces (erase the hotstring trigger).

`{Text}`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Text)</sup> used to enable the text send mode to interpret the latter curly brackets literally.

---

Alternatively, you could take a look at this library to create *dynamic hotstrings*
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/98728-dynamic-hotstrings/
I can't speak for good it is (or isn't), haven't really used it.

Comment: thanx - great works like a charm 
but it doesn't solve my problems, but that's because I didn't specify exactly what I need. I hoped I can use sometimes more than one. eg something like : #bn a bc
But many thanx that helps me a lot and I will try and look the link and understand more.

Comment: You can use the `Input` command just fine to get input for any other string you have. Doesn't have to be just two characters. Maybe specifying an endkey would be good if you want to capture a varied length input.